# unexpected squid behaviour (cache for openSUSE updates)

Tags: opensuse, upgrade, proxy, squid, yast

With no previous experience I have just set up a `squid` proxy. Its only purpose is to prevent that all the Linux systems (openSUSE) download their updates from the Internet.

A proxy can easily be configured for the openSUSE update tool. `tcpdump` shows that the other systems access the proxy and the proxy accesses the repositories.

What I don't understand: After a distro upgrade the first online update is supposed to be 400 MiB to 700 MiB (that's what YaST says before starting the update). But the `squid` storage directory contains only about 80 MiB data.

The `access.log` shows both hits and misses. Even if for some strange reasons the Linux systems would access different servers (Is there some kind of DNS-intransparent redirection?) then I would expect the proxy storage to be at least as big as the biggest download.

The repositories are `http`, not `https` thus there should not be a problem for a proxy.

**problem found**

[This link](http://wiki.jessen.ch/index/How_to_cache_openSUSE_repositories_with_Squid) in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/125610/32191) provides the information why squid does not work well here:

> packages are downloaded using segmented downloading spread over multiple mirrors, which together makes it impossible for squid to do much caching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this tutorial: [How to cache openSUSE repositories with Squid](http://wiki.jessen.ch/index/How_to_cache_openSUSE_repositories_with_Squid).

*excerpt*

> How to make your local Squid web cache work with openSUSE repositories and the openSUSE network installation process. In effect, how to run a fully autonomous, local on-demand repository mirror. Even with a high-speed ADSL internet connection, savings of up to 60% are easily achieved.

Below are the step by step details from that article.

#### Step by step

1. Squid

   The Squid web-proxy is the key element in this setup, so a working Squid installation is prerequisite. Setting up Squid is not as complicated as it may appear, but you'll have to consult squid documentation, it's outside the scope of this article. Whether you prefer directing access using environment variables http_proxy et al, or if you run a transparent proxy (like I do), is not really important.

   **Note:** the setup here works for Squid 2.7, I don't think the storeurl_rewrite feature has been implemented in Squid 3.x yet.
2. jesred

   jesred is the URL rewriter. It's fairly mature, but fully functional. ([original webpage](http://www.linofee.org/~jel/webtools/jesred/)). I had to make a couple of changes to make it fully compatible with [squid 2.7](http://www.squid-cache.org/):

   - [jesred-1.3.tar.gz](http://files.jessen.ch/jesred-1.3.tar.gz)

   For the moment, it does not come packaged, you'll have to build it from scratch:

   ```
   tar xzvf <tarball>
   cd jesred-1.3
   make
   ```

   Installation: when you're done, copy the binary jesred into `/usr/local/bin` or whatever your preferred location for your own binaries is.

   The config file for jesred: `/etc/squid/jesred.conf`

   ```
   allow = /etc/squid/redirector.acl
   rules = /etc/squid/opensuse-redirect.rules
   redirect_log = /var/log/squid/redirect.log
   rewrite_log = /var/log/squid/rewrite.log
   ```

   Using `/etc/squid/redirector.acl` you can control which clients' requests the rewriter should process, but I find this is actually easier to control with Squid's ACL and storeurl_access directive, so I enable for all clients:

   ```
   # rewrite all URLs from
   0.0.0.0/0
   ```
3. /etc/squid/squid.conf

   Configuration: add the following lines to `/etc/squid/squid.conf`
       storeurl_rewrite_program /usr/bin/jesred
       storeurl_rewrite_children 5

   ```
   acl metalink req_mime_type application/metalink4+xml
   storeurl_access deny metalink 

   storeurl_access allow localnet
   storeurl_access allow localhost

   acl localhost src 127.0.0.0/8
   acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16
   ```
4. fetcher206 logfile

   Amend `/etc/squid/squid./conf` as follows:

   ```
   logformat f206 %{%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S}tl %Ss/%03Hs %rm %ru %mt
   access_log /var/log/squid/fetch206.log f206
   ```

   This log will be read by fetcher206.

   To prevent it growing too big, add the following to `/etc/logrotate.d/`:

   ```
   /var/log/squid/fetch206.log {
      compress
      dateext
      maxage 365
      rotate 5
      size=+4M
      notifempty
      missingok
      create 640 squid root
      sharedscripts
      postrotate
       /etc/init.d/squid reload
      endscript
   }
   ```
5. squid delay pool

   This is an optional step - depending on your available downstream bandwidth, you may want to restrict what is used by fetcher206 for retrieving the repository files. This prevents

   - slowing down the current installation and
   - abuse of the internet connection

   ```
   delay_pools 1
   delay_class 1 1
   delay_access 1 allow localhost
   delay_parameters 1 1000000/1000000
   ```

   Add the above to /etc/squid/squid.conf - it defines one delay_pool, only accessible from localhost (which is where fetcher206 will be running wget) with a maximum bandwidth of 1MByte/sec.

   If you have other http/proxy traffic originating from localhost, you could just add another 127.0.0.x address, and use that specifically for fetcher206.
6. mirror database

   We need a current list of the available openSUSE mirrors. This can be retrieved from mirrors.opensuse.org. For the time being, I use XSL to parse the HTML page, but I hope to move to a suitably formatted list direct from MirrorBrain.

   ```
   mkdir -p /var/lib/fetcher206
   cp tarball/Makefile.mirrors /var/lib/fetcher206/Makefile
   cp tarball/extract* /var/lib/fetcher206/
   make -C /var/lib/fetcher206
   cp tarball/opensuse_mirrors.cron /etc/cron.d/opensuse_mirrors
   ```
7. reload squid

   When you've come this far, it's time to reload squid with

   ```
   squid -k reconfigure
   ```
8. fetcher206

   fetcher206 is, for the time being, a PHP script. Install it by simply copying it into /usr/bin. It has a few hard-coded options, such as number of wgets to run concurrently, name of logfile etc.

   fetcher206 does not yet have a systemd service unit, nor an LSB init-script. For the time being, you simply start it with:

   ```
   startproc -s -q /usr/bin/fetcher206
   ```

#### References

- [Zypp-proxy - A proxy cache server for zypper updates](https://features.opensuse.org/306896)
- [CONFIGURING A BASIC SQUID PROXY ON OPENSUSE LINUX](http://theurbanpenguin.com/wp/?p=99)

Comment: I just realize that this explains the cache misses but not the small amount of cached data.